# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'delete' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Tags: php

I have this php code to display a sql table. I'm trying to set piece of code te delete rows. I saw an example on the internet. But I get this (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'delete' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';') error when I'm using that code on line24.What Can I do About this?

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$conn=odbc_connect('MOS2.41','','');
if (!$conn)
{exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}
$sql="SELECT * FROM Docnumber";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs)
{exit("Error in SQL");}
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>";
echo "<th>PatId</th>";
echo "<th>Docnumber</th>";
echo "<th>Delete</th>
</tr>";
while ($row = odbc_fetch_row($rs))
{
$PatId=odbc_result($rs,"PatId");
$Docnumber=odbc_result($rs,"Docnumber");
echo "<tr><td>$PatId</td>";
echo "<td>$Docnumber</td>";
echo "<td><a href="delete.php?id={$row['id']}">Delete row</a></td><tr/>";

 }
odbc_close($conn);
echo "</table>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is not properly enclosed at:

```
echo "<td><a href="delete.php?id={$row['id']}">Delete row</a></td><tr/>";
                  ^ here
```

Escape it with a `\`:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"delete.php?id={$row['id']}\">Delete row</a></td><tr/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
echo "<td><a href="delete.php?id={$row['id']}">Delete row</a></td><tr/>";
```

To

```
echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id='. $row['id'].'">Delete row</a></td><tr/>';
```

There are wrong use of `{`.

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$conn=odbc_connect('MOS2.41','','');
if (!$conn)
{exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}
$sql="SELECT * FROM Docnumber";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs)
{exit("Error in SQL");}
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>";
echo "<th>PatId</th>";
echo "<th>Docnumber</th>";
echo "<th>Delete</th>
</tr>";
while ($row = odbc_fetch_row($rs))
{
$PatId=odbc_result($rs,"PatId");
$Docnumber=odbc_result($rs,"Docnumber");
echo "<tr><td>$PatId</td>";
echo "<td>$Docnumber</td>";
echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id='. $row['id'].'">Delete row</a></td><tr/>';

 }
odbc_close($conn);
echo "</table>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Better answers include an explanation (text), not just a code dump.

Comment: Ok. Now I have a column with the delete link. How should I go further to delete rows from the table? Is it necessary to make another php page?